# The gap model in Pine does not work well. How can I fix it?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Buy Entry Condition.
If today's opening price is a certain amount lower than the previous day's low (in this case, 5), buy at today's opening price and close at today's close price.

Sell Entry Condition
If today's opening price is a certain amount higher than the previous day's high price (set here as 5), sell at today's opening price and close at today's close price.

Thus, the position should be closed during the day from the opening price to the closing price.

The Pine script I wrote is as follows
I read that if I set process_orders_on_close = true, I can close at the closing price, so I did this

When I actually run it on the chart, it does not work as intended.
(The position holding period is not 1 day)

How can I fix this?

```
//@version=5
strategy("Gap Strategy", shorttitle="GS", overlay=true, process_orders_on_close = true)

//buyCondition,sellCondition
buyCondition = open < low[1] - 5
sellCondition = open > high[1] + 5

//Entry
if(buyCondition)
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)
if(sellCondition)
    strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short)

//Close
strategy.close("Buy")
strategy.close("Sell")
```

Since the condition for entry at the opening price is that the price must be a certain amount higher or lower than the opening price, I was wondering if there is a problem with the fact that the calculation cannot yet be done at the opening price.

In that case, it might be a good idea to specify the entry and close times, but in that case, I could not try because I do not understand how it should be programmed.